# MBProgressHUD not staying on screen for designated time using hide afterDelay

Tags: ios, xcode, mbprogresshud

I've searched around SO for quite awhile looking for a solution (plus a large amount of time troubleshooting this issue on my own.) I'm trying to create a general-purpose pop-up message to use at various places in my application, but I am having trouble keeping the message on the screen. Specifically, I'm trying to leave a message on the screen for 2 seconds before it automatically disappears. I'm using MBProgressHUD to accomplish this. Here is my code:

```
-(void)showMessage{
    MBProgressHUD *buttonClickMessage;
    buttonClickMessage = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    buttonClickMessage.labelText = @"Test";
    buttonClickMessage.mode = MBProgressHUDModeText;
    [self.view addSubview:buttonClickMessage];
    [buttonClickMessage show:YES];
    [buttonClickMessage hide:YES afterDelay:10];
}
```

Anytime I attempt to call `[self showMessage]` in my code the message only flashes briefly on the screen, i.e.: it doesn't last the 10 seconds as specified in the code I included above. Anyone know why? Thank you.

Also, here is the code from MBProgressHUD:

```
- (void)hide:(BOOL)animated afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay {
    [self performSelector:@selector(hideDelayed:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:animated] afterDelay:delay];
}

- (void)hideDelayed:(NSNumber *)animated {
    [self hide:[animated boolValue]];
}
```

Comment: I don't know much about `MBProgressHUD`, but would calling: `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:buttonClickMessage];` help you?

Comment: No, the view shows fine, the problem has to do with it only showing for a split second before disappearing.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a problem with `MBProgressHUD` ?

Comment: That's a possibility. I posted the code from MBProgressHUD above.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see anything wrong with that code really

Comment: The question is how are you using it, from your code it looks you are doing it on `self.view` and your `self.view` is disappearing, so HUD too. I suggest not to add HUD on `self.view` rather add on `Appdelegate.window`, I hope it will work.

Comment: Do you have an example how this would work?

Comment: To add MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES]; to remove [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];